# Asp Button is not binding on Event Handler

Tags: html, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm using asp.net button control in my project but this button is unable to bind its Click event, ,I've written button code as

```
<asp:Button ID="btnProcess" runat="server" Text="Process" class="btn btn-default" OnClick="btnProcess_Click"   />
```

and Code behind as this

```
 protected void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 {
     MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
     MultiView1.Visible = true;
     GridView.DataSource = Session["Table"];
     GridView.DataBind();
 }
```

I'm getting this error when I run that code

> 'ASP.fileuploadingmodule_aspx' does not contain a definition
>   for 'btnProcess_Click'

in fact on double clicking this button generates a javascript snippet instead of .cs event handler.

like this :

```
<script runat="server">

    protected void btnProcess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

</script>
```

Project is made on asp.net 2.0 and visual studio 2012.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you check the aspx page header. Lets say you have a.aspx? Is it binded to a.aspx.cs page?

Comment: yes all other controls are working fine but not button controls

Comment: build your project and restart it again and check.

Comment: on a side note, _where_ exactly is your button aspx code inside the gridiview ??

Comment: I've done that as well nothing happens

Comment: @AleyaAli: Does it has `desginer.cs` page ?

Comment: its under Multiview view but I Put it in forms tags and check, same thing happen

Comment: can you check that it contains `btnProcess` the button _ID_

Comment: yes, actually before this error, this project was not updating my code on meta data then I created a new project and add files in this one, at that time I need to build my project under release but I was not able to find Release option in Batch builder. I think this error is related to that.

Comment: might be, do you got the _solution_ to this ?

Comment: yes button id is btnProcess and my event handler name is btnProcess_Click

Comment: yes I need to build project under Release option but this option is not there in batch build. so last time I created new web and add existing files to it.